# Add a local DLL by reference VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference

I am using VS 10. I have a DLL that I created locally. I want to add the DLL as a reference (to a website that I am creating) so I can edit the DL (also it helps for when I am steping through from the site to the DLL) from the website without having another instance of VS open.

I know there are similar questions, but I havent been able to locate a solution on them.

Comment: What do you mean by "DL"? Do you mean a DLL, created from a class library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I took to add a local DLL to a website I am developing locally.

1. Right Click on Solution in Solution Explorer of VS10 and choose 'Add Existing Project'
2. Select the .csproj file in the DLL folder
3. Right Click on the website project choose Add Reference
4. Click the Projects Tab
5. The DLL should be listed. Choose it.
6. Right click on your DLL in the solution explorer and Select Rebuild
7. Build the Website though the Solution explorer